# How to get current facing direction vector 2D?

Tags: math, vector, rotation, godot

So I am developing a game in 2D in Godot and I want to see a line from the center of my sprite to its facing position. I have the sprite rotating and moving along the rotation direction but when I try to create vector out of that its very wrong. For example the vector line is going from the center of the sprite to near (0,0) position on the screen.

```
 public override void _Draw()
{
    Vector2 rotationDirection = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(sprite.GlobalRotation) , Mathf.Sin(sprite.GlobalRotation)) - sprite.GlobalPosition;
    DrawLine(sprite.GlobalPosition, rotationDirection, Colors.Red, 2f);

}
```

EDIT:

Fixed it it works now.

```
 public override void _Draw()
{         
    DrawLine(sprite.GlobalPosition, sprite.GlobalPosition + new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(sprite.GlobalRotation), Mathf.Sin(sprite.GlobalRotation)) * 50f, Colors.Red, 2f);

}
```

Comment: When you solve your own problem, posting an answer to your own question (as you had done) is the encourage behavior (explaining it is also encouraged, as it would help people with similar problems). Furthermore, the system will let you accept your own answer after a grace period. Doing this you signal that the problem the solved. Leaving the question without an answer makes it seem at first glace as if it were an unsolved problem.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would have been to add a `Line2D` child node. You can see the effect right away in the editor, and there's no need for any maths.

This might also be more efficient, because custom `_draw` functions don't play nice with Godot's geometry batching.